# How do you explicitly instantiate a function with a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a C++ function of the form (it's a bit more complicated; this is the MWE):

```
template <typename T>
struct Meas {
   T time;
   T value;
};

template <typename T, template <typename U> class container>
      T func(typename container<Meas<T>>::const_iterator start,
             typename container<Meas<T>>::const_iterator end)
{
    T c = 0;
    while (start != end) {
       c += start->value;
    }
    return c;
}
```

I'm having trouble explicitly instantiating it. I've tried most permutations of:

```
template double func<double, X>(std::deque<Meas<double>>::const_iterator, 
                                std::deque<Meas<double>>::const_iterator);
```

with X being one of the following:

```
std::deque
template std::deque
template std::deque<double>
std::deque<double>
template <typename U> std::deque<U>
template <typename U> std::deque
```

but none of them compile in Xcode 9.0. The most common error is:

> Explicit instantiation of 'func' does not refer to a function template, variable template, member function, member class, or static data member

How should I correctly explicitly instantiate this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two issues, the 1st one is that [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) has two template parameters (the 2nd one has a default value `std::allocator<T>`), which doesn't match the template template parameter declaration of `func`. You can change `template <typename U> class container` to `template <typename, typename> class container` or use [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) like `template <typename...> class container`, which allows any number of the template parameters.

The 2nd one is that `func` takes parameters of type `container<Meas<T>>::const_iterator`, which doesn't match the type in the explicit instantiation (i.e. `std::deque<double>::const_iterator`).

The following should work.

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class container>
      T func(typename container<Meas<T>>::const_iterator start,
             typename container<Meas<T>>::const_iterator end) 
{
    ...
}

template 
double func<double, std::deque>(std::deque<Meas<double>>::const_iterator, 
                                std::deque<Meas<double>>::const_iterator);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/MAKU15841)

Answer (score 2):

`std::deque` is a `template<class, class>class` with a defaulted 2nd parameter, not a `template<class>class`.  So it doesn't qualify.

Sometimes `template <class...> class container` can fix this, with `X` being `std::deque`.

---

In your simplified example, the `container` serves no useful purpose.  You just want the iterator value type.  Odds are this kind of pointlessness remains in your real code, as wanting the container from which an iterator comes is not how the container/iterator design of the std library is designed.  You should not care.

Use `using T=typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;` to extract `T` from an iterator type instead of what you are doing.

```
template <class It, class T=typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>
T func(It start, It end)
{
  T c = 0;
  while (start != end) {
    c += start->value;
    ++start;
  }
  return c;
}
```

this can deduce its template arguments, like 99% of good template functions should.

Then if you need to instantiate it:

```
template double func<std::deque<double>::const_iterator, double>(std::deque<double>::const_iterator, 
                            std::deque<double>::const_iterator);
```

the `,double` may not be needed, my in-head compiler is uncertain and I don't care to check it.

Comment: The ... change works. Thanks! The point of using the container is that the iterator value type is known by the development environment when writing the function, so it can do all the member checking and smart variable completion as you type. Also, if we expect the value type (here, Meas<T>) to be something particular, it seems an odd scheme to allow it to be anything.

Comment: I had a typo in my question before (now fixed): the template parameters to std::deque in the instantiation were wrong. It seems like this caused the confusion.